# Parte do meu código parece não passar pelo Babel antes de chegar no Uglify

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babel, laravel, ofuscação

Não estou conseguindo gerar o build de produção da minha aplicação com o Laravel Mix. Ao tentar gerar o build, o npm me diz que houve um erro ao tentar rodar o UglifyJs:

> /js/app.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected token: operator (>) [./~/bootstrap/js/src/modal.js:11,0][/js/app.js:34863,20]

Fui olhar o código e na linha 11 do modal.js (do bootstrap 4 alpha, que estou importando por componente conforme necessário) tem uma *arrow function*. É ela que está causando o erro. Se eu retiro o `import` do modal.js, o build completa normalmente.

Meu diagnóstico é que esse arquivo não está passando pelo Babel antes de chegar no Uglify. Isso me parece muito estranho, já que o resto do meu código parece estar passando normalmente pelo Babel.

Meu webpack.mix.js é o padrão:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Não tenho muita experiência com o Laravel Mix, e estou longe de decifrar todos os mistérios do webpack... Alguém sabe por que isso está acontecendo, e como resolver?

Comment: PS: existem algumas referências a erros similares no GitHub do Laravel Mix, mas nenhuma das soluções indicadas ali funcionou pra mim.